# ffmpeg margin from top on image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

I am using ffmpeg for encoding and adding a video on png image, my image width and height is equal 720px. But I want to add the video to image from 70px height to 490px

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=720:490[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=1:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

An example of how this code works:

[image]

But the problem is that I want to give a `70px` margin from to the video from the top.

So the output I want is:

[image]

I've said what code I used and tried, but I don't know how to give a 70px margin from top to the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the position of the `y` coordinate:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=720:490[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=y=70:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

See the [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more information.